# How to prettify JSON response that contains stringified JSON

Tags: postman

[image]

The server response I'm testing contains stringified json which is hard to read (see the "pay" field in the screenshot). Is there any way to prettify the response further?

As it stands, i have to copy the "pay" field, unescape it and then paste it in jsoneditoronline.org to view the payload in the "pay" field in a structured format.

A workaround I was considering was perhaps using the postman visualize feature, but only as a last resort.

Comment: That's already been 'prettified' by Postman so you're not going to get more than that in the default response body. You could take that part of the response and do it in the console though or in the visualizer like you mentioned.

Comment: thanks Danny, looks like that's what I'll have to do

Comment: Should be a really simple visualizer script to do this. Drop me a message on the Postman community site if you need any pointers. https://community.postman.com 

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to Danny for nudging me towards the visualizer. This is what I came up with:

### Elements of the solution

- use JSON.stringify to output prettified json (notice the params passed to JSON.stringify)
- use css white-space: pre-wrap to respect the whitespace in the prettified string
- in the handlebars template, simply display the string and apply the css

### Details

put this script in the Postman test

```
var template = `
    <style type="text/css">
        div {white-space: pre-wrap;}
    </style>
    <div>
        {{response}}
    </div>
`;

const payloadJson = JSON.parse(pm.response.json().pay);
const payload = JSON.stringify(payloadJson, null, 4)

pm.visualizer.set(template, {
    response: payload
});
```

### Result

[image]

Comment: Does the same thing, but you can also use `null` instead of `undefined` for the 2nd stringify arg (and I believe null is more-widely accepted + shorter to type).

Answer (score 0):

You can treat the whole JSON string as a template and wrap with a PRE tag.

```
const jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
const payload = jsonData.access_token.split('.')[1];
const parsed = JSON.parse(atob(payload));
const prettyString = JSON.stringify(parsed,null,2);
pm.visualizer.set("<pre>"+prettyString+"</pre>")
```